# $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\not\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I was asked to prove the following statement:
$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \not\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$.
Intuitively seems simple enough, but I have not been trained in rigorously proving inclusion cases with cartesian products.
Your help will be greatly appreciated and thank you beforehand for you welcome assistance.
This is as much as I have been able to do:
[image]

Comment: \times will give you $\times$ for multiplication.

Comment: To show that $A\nsubseteq B$ you need only find an element of $A$ that is not an element of $B$. Can you find an ordered pair of integers that is not an element of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb N$?

Comment: For a counterexample, you only have to choose the second entry of the pair negative.

Comment: I'm stuck on how you got your first line. $\forall a,b,c\in Z[(a,b)\to \cdots$. This is not a well formed formula. $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair. You can't say $(a,b)\to$. You need to make a statement about $(a,b)$ such as $(a,b)\in Z \times Z$ to put into your implication. One correct way to write your statement is:
$$\forall a,b [(a,b)\in Z\times Z \to (a,b)\in Z\times N].$$

Comment: You ought to learn how to write a double-struck $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb N$. That’s how $\mathbf Z$ and $\mathbf N$ were written on chalkboards and paper for many years . . . until the double-struck notation became so popular and iconic that it replaced its parent notation entirely, even in typed text.

Answer (score 1):

For any three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ with $A \neq \emptyset$, $A \times B \subseteq A \times C$ if and only if $B \subseteq C$. So, since $\mathbb{Z} \neq \emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Z} \not\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \not\subseteq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$(1,-1)\in\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z.$$

> But $$(1,-1)\notin \Bbb Z\times \Bbb N.$$

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a single counter example.

$A \subset B$ means for all $x \in A$ then $x \in B$.  So $A\not \subset B$ means there exists at least one $a\in A$ but $a \not \in B$.

So to show $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \not \subset \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ all you have to do is find ***one***  $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ where $(a,b)\not \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$.

That is find just ***one*** $a,b$ pair where $a \in \mathbb Z, b \in \mathbb Z$ but either $a \not \in \mathbb N$ or $b\not \in \mathbb Z$.

Well, obviously $b\in \mathbb Z$ and $b\not \in \mathbb Z$ is impossible, but surely finding an $a\in \mathbb Z$ where $a \not \in \mathbb N$ is possible, isn't it?

You just need *ONE* example.

So how about $(-27, 534)$?   $-27\in \mathbb Z$ and $534 \in \mathbb Z$ so $(-27,534)\in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.  But $-27 \not \in \mathbb N$ so $(-27, 534) \not \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$.  ANd that's it.  It is NOT the case then every $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is an element of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ because we find one where that wasn't true.

So $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z \not \subset \mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$

That's all there is to it.